# Javascript/JQuery to create a div -Simple Way

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code in a div:

```
    <div class="user_event my_background">
        <%= image_tag("events_pics/boom.png", :class=> 'event_pic_small') %>
        <h6 class="event_info">Event_1: Frame: 974</h6>
        <a class="btn btn-mini btn-danger pull-right " href="#"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a>
    </div>
```

and I want this to be appended into an other element each time I click on a button. Anyway the main question is, Is there an easy way to create the above div using javascript? for example a function that takes that as an argument and creates it? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you can use jQuery then

```
$(".user_event").clone().appendTo("#MyTargetElement");
```

**Edit**:

Instead of creating a the div again and again, I'd recommend that you keep it hidden in some element and get it using that hidden element's id and append it to your target element.

```
<div id="myhiddenelement" style="display:none;">
 <div class="user_event my_background">
        <%= image_tag("events_pics/boom.png", :class=> 'event_pic_small') %>
        <h6 class="event_info">Event_1: Frame: 974</h6>
        <a class="btn btn-mini btn-danger pull-right " href="#"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
("#MyTargetElement").append($("#myhiddenelement").html());
```

Answer (score 2):

This simple Jquery function will set the html inside the element selected to whatever you want.

```
$("SomeElement").html("<div class='user_event my_background'>...</div>")
```

Just specify the element you want to add the html to and the rest of you html as the argument and you are good to go. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use this script:

```
$("body").prepend('<div>').addClass("user_event").addClass("my_background");
function addElement()
{
    $(".user_event.my_background").append('<h6 class="event_info">Event_1: Frame: 974</h6>');
    $(".user_event.my_background").append('<a class="btn btn-mini btn-danger pull-right " href="#"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a>');
}
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
function append_to_what(id)//id can be any css3 selector
{var div=document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML='<%= image_tag("events_pics/boom.png", :class=> "event_pic_small") %><h6 class="event_info">Event_1: Frame: 974</h6><a class="btn btn-mini btn-danger pull-right " href="#"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a>';
'
div.className='user_event my_background';
document.querySelector(id).appendChild(div);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check Jquery where you can access a div using class name.